# How do i apply inner join or left join to my query?

Tags: sql, select, inner-join

This is my query :

```
select p.cod_produs, p.title, c.category as cname, p.description, p.short_desc, p.img1, p.price, p.qty, p.isActive, p.disponibilitate
from tblproducts p
inner join tblcategory c on p.cat_id = c.id
```

I have two tables : `tblcategory` &  `tblproducts.` In my `tblcategory` i have an attribute `cat_id`. There are possibilities when my product does not have any categories assigned, in that case the `cat_id`'s value is `0`.  My query returns all of the products which have categories. So , I want to create a query which returns me all of the products with categories and without(return 0 ). How can i do that ? thx

Comment: Read up on the WHERE clause of SQL queries.

Comment: And also LEFT JOIN if I understand the question rightly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Inner Join :** The INNER JOIN keyword selects all rows from both tables as long as there is a match between the columns in both tables. i.e. Only if both tables have the matching column, it is added to the result.

**Left Join  :**  The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all rows from the left table (table1), with the matching rows in the right table (table2). The result is NULL in the right side when there is no match. I think this is what you need (from what I interpreted from your question).

Read more on joins [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp)